# How to validate my custom WooCommerce checkout field at the end?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom checkout field for WooCommerce. I have also added the validation. But after clicking on place order, my custom fields also checked if it is validated or not. But, I want to check if my custom field is valid or not at the end. I mean, all other required fields will be check and after that my custom field will be checked.
Below is my code structure:

```
function otp_func($checkout) {
  .............................
}
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'otp_func', 10 );
  add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process','my_custom_checkout_field_process');
  function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
        ..........................
   }
```

And below is my validation code which I want to run at the end if all the other fields validate successfully:

```
if (!$_POST['otp_field']) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'OTP field is blank' ), 'error' );
} else if ( $_POST['otp_field'] != $otp_verify_report ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid OTP or OTP has been expired!' ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. It is doing the same thing where I am using add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');.
But I want to validate it only if all the required fields are valid.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to validate new field.

Add Below code in theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout', 10, 2 );

function wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    if ( ! empty( $posted['otp_field'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'OTP field is blank' ), 'error' );
    } else if ( $posted['otp_field'] != $otp_verify_report ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid OTP or OTP has been expired!' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not work. If all other required fields not validate, then it even should not check validation for my custom field. Only check the validation of my custom fields if other required fields are validated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with:

```
function customise_checkout_field_process()
{
    if (!$_POST['the_customised_field_name']) wc_add_notice(__('the warning message') , 'error');
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what type of code is it:
 if (!$_POST['the_customised_field_name']) wc_add_notice(__('the warning message') , 'error');

Comment: And also I dodn't want to check if required field one by one.

Comment: To validate your custom field, only this one.